# Is there any r function to convert the column headers( eg:Jan 2018, feb 2018 and so on)"Jan 2018" to "Jan-18" in R?

Tags: r

I want to find a code to convert column headers ( jan 2018, feb 2018, mar 2018 etc )  into jan-18, feb-18 etc.
The following code is used to create the template:

```
xx <- dcast(yy, type + name + code + Detail ~ Yearmon, value.var = "emp")
```

I have tried several ways to convert yearmon to "jan-18" format.

```
xx %>% mutate(levels = apply(expand.grid(month.abb, substr(1990:2019,3,4)), 1, paste, collapse="-"))
```

> Error: Column `levels` must be length 772 (the number of rows) or one, not 360

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix is that `dcast` accepts functions to be applied within the formula itself.  So, replace the space with `-` using `sub` on the 'Yearmon'  in `dcast` formula

```
dcast(yy, type+name+code+Detail~tolower(sub(" \\d{2}", "-", Yearmon)), 
             value.var="emp")
```

If we want to order based on the 'Yearmon', an option is to convert to `yearmon` class (`as.yearmon` from `zoo`)  - added a reproducible example

```
library(zoo)
set.seed(24)
yy <- data.frame(name = rep(letters[1:4], each = 6), 
   emp = rnorm(24), Yearmon = paste(month.abb, 2018))
yy$Yearmon <- as.yearmon(yy$Yearmon)
out <- dcast(yy, name ~ Yearmon, value.var = 'emp')
nm1 <- grep("^[A-Za-z]{3} \\d{4}", names(out))
names(out)[nm1] <- tolower(sub(" \\d{2}", "-", names(out)[nm1]))
names(out)
#[1] "name"   "jan-18" "feb-18" "mar-18" "apr-18" "may-18" "jun-18" 
#[8] "jul-18" "aug-18" "sep-18" "oct-18" "nov-18" "dec-18"
```

Comment: Thanks for your code.  I tried your code. It is showing Jan-2019, feb-2019 etc. I want to jan-18, feb-18 etc.

Comment: Thank you again. I tried the updated code. But I still got the same result(jan-2018). I just want to take out the first two digits of the year(jan-18)

Comment: @Anjaly Just to confirm `tolower(sub(" \\d{2}", "-", "Jan 2018"))#
[1] "jan-18"`

Comment: Thanks again. I got the right format "jan-18". Now the problem is column names  showing in alphabetical order ( apr-19, aug-18, dec-18, jan-19 likewise).

Comment: @Anjaly I would suggest to use `as.yearmon` from `zoo` i.e. `yy$Yearmon <- as.yearmon(yy$Yearmon)` and then apply the same code

Comment: @Anjaly You can check the update.  I created a reproducible example.  The issue was that once we mutate in the formula, the order goes in alphabetic.  An option is to rename the columns after the `dcast`

Comment: @Anjaly the issue is not in the `sub`, it is the order based on character class sorting by alphabetic order.  In your code you selected only a single digit, so it got removed instead of `[[:digit:]]{2}`

Comment: @Anjaly My updated code works and you wouldn't have any problems with that assuming the data structure is similar